# Access to [PFUser currentUser] causing deadlock

Tags: parse-platform, pfuser

Getting a deadlock occasionally when several threads trying to access [PFUser currentUser] when using parse iOS sdk v1.2.20

It looks like whenever I make a PFQuery call or PFCloud function call, these operations also access [PFUser currentUser], so there's increase chance of deadlock if you are making queries from separate threads.

Anyone else find a solution for this, I doubt parse even is aware of the problem as they closed these related issues long ago:
https://www.parse.com/questions/parse-locking-up-the-main-thread-possible-deadlock
And this one:
https://www.parse.com/questions/occasional-freezing-at-pfuser-currentuser

Comment: You may check if your issue corresponds to this bug and subscribe to it: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1459246127692533/

Comment: I also have that problem. It looks like it appears more often with local data storage enabled. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

Parse has released an update with a possible fix of the `currentUser` deadlock.

Hopefully this fixes your situation.

Check the changelog and try updating to [Parse SDK v1.7.2](https://parse.com/docs/downloads).