# Major bug in Parse: [PFUser currentUser] deadlocks

Tags: multithreading, crash, parse-platform, deadlock, pfuser

The issue of PFUser deadlocking from thread contention via parse background calls has been raised numerous times by the Parse community, but Parse has chosen not to deal with this giant bug in the framework. Does anyone know of a work around for this issue?

Other apparent reports of this issue:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/649920188390439/
https://www.parse.com/questions/ios-api-apparent-deadlock-in-main-thread-v1213
https://www.parse.com/questions/occasional-freezing-at-pfuser-currentuser
https://www.parse.com/questions/deadlock-on-pfuser-currentuser-ios-sdk-1219
```

Comment: Looks like your issue corresponds to this bug. If so, please subscribe to it and provide any extra info you have: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1459246127692533/

Comment: I also have that problem. It looks like it appears more often with local data storage enabled. Any workarounds?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419611/access-to-pfuser-currentuser-causing-deadlock.