# Parse SDK deadlocks on first background call within [PFUser currentUser]

Tags: ios, parse-platform, deadlock

I am finding that if I kill my app and then on every subsequent launch Parse deadlocks. Version: 1.6.4

[image: Stack trace with getFirstObjectInBackground blocked]

I'm not the first to have reported this it seems, e.g.

[Major bug in Parse: [PFUser currentUser] deadlocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25443279/major-bug-in-parse-pfuser-currentuser-deadlocks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this was fixed by Parse, in v1.7.2 (possibly earlier).